# Angular: Pass params to $http.get

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I'm trying to pass a params object to the `$http.get()` service. My params look like this:

```
var params = {
  one: value,
  two: value
}
```

And I'm trying to pass them into my function like so:

```
$http.get('/someUrl', params)
.success(function(data) {
   // stuff
})
.error(function(data) {
   // error stuff
});
```

Is this the correct way to go about doing this?

Comment: Are they path/query params?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The second argument of `$http` is a *config* object (**[see documentation](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.6/docs/api/ng/service/$http#get)**). Amongst other properties, the *config* object accepts a `params` property:

- params – `{Object.<string|Object>}` – Map of strings or objects which will be serialized with the paramSerializer and appended as GET parameters.

Therefore you have to pass the parameters as such

```
var config = {
    params: {
        one: value,
        two: value
    }
}

$http.get('/someUrl', config).then(...)
```

Suppose the values for the parameters are respectively '1' and '2', `$http` will send a GET request to the following url:

```
/someUrl?one=1&two=2
```

As a side note, try to avoid using `success` and `error` functions on `$http`. They have been deprecated as of angular 1.4.4. Use the methods `then` with a success and an error callback instead, or then with only a success callback and `catch`.

Comment: This is fantastic! Thanks for this.

Answer (score 3):

## Service/Factory

For the actual call use a factory or service that you can inject to the controllers you need it in. This is an example factory passing parameters

```
.factory('Chats', function ($http, $rootScope, $stateParams) {
  return {
      all: function () {
          return $http.get('http://ip_address_or_url:3000/chats', { params: { user_id: $rootScope.session } })
      }
  };
});
```

## Controller

In your controller you use the service like this

```
.controller('ChatsCtrl', function ($scope, Chats) {
    Chats.all().success(function (response) {
        $scope.chats = response;
    })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

I have faced similar issue in recent time and I had to add few additional details to request (I used accepted answer with some headers):

```
$http.get(url, {
    params: {
        paramOne: valueOne,
        paramTwo: valueTwo,
        ...
    },
    headers: {
        'key': 'value'
    },
    // responseType was required in my case as I was basically
    // retrieving PDf document using this REST endpoint
    // This is not required in your case, 
    // keeping it for somebody else's reference
    responseType: 'arraybuffer'
}).success(
    function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // do some stuff here with data
    }).error(function(data) {
        // do some stuff here with data
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The $http [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) suggest that the second argument to the $http.get method is an object which you can pass with it "param" object.

Try something like this:

```
$http.get('/someUrl', {params: params})
.success(function(data) {
   // stuff
})
.error(function(data) {
   // error stuff
});
```